# "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." to admin

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have my token for admin, the booking entries is allowed in Insomnia but would not be allowed DRF display. I am missing something please? Is there way to provide the token for it to be allowed?

[image]

[image]

```
#view.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Booking, Menu
from .serializers import BookingSerializer, MenuSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework import generics
from datetime import datetime
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.contrib import messages



def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html')


class UserRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class BookingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

Comment: token will not send in bearer

Answer (score 0):

[image]Select Headers Key will be **Authorization** and value will be like this

```
Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b
```

Comment: Thank you Tanveer, where should the headers key be selected? It shows in Insomnia, my concern is on the DFR browser

Comment: in your given image the Header is under endpoint

Comment: I have done that but still not showing on the browser. I do not have any issues with Insomnia. It works fine. It is on the browser that I am concerned

Comment: I think you are missing something so that's why you facing the not authorized msg

Comment: first please add  path('auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')) in your urls.py file

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ have a look into detail docs

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `session`  authentication class because here you used token for authentication

I mean authentication classes overrides.

So, remove session authentication class only put token authentication class

But, you want to authenticate with browsable you need to remove token authentication and need to put session authentication class.

If you want authenticate with with token you need to POSTMAN or other third -party API testing tool which support token authentication
and you need to remove session authentication and need to put token authentication class

#### settings for token authentication (test with Postman or other third -party API testing tool)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

#### settings for session authentication (test with browsable api which provides DRF built-in)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```